# Issues using Reaver on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, wpa

I’m trying to use [Reaver](https://code.google.com/p/reaver-wps/) on my own network. I’ve followed the instructions from [this](http://lifehacker.com/5873407/how-to-crack-a-wi+fi-networks-wpa-password-with-reaver) site and I’m getting this error message:

> WARNING: Failed to associate with 00:00:00:00:00:00 (ESSID: casaWitty)
>   (changed mac address .. )

I’m not sure what I'm doing wrong. I’ve used following command:

```
sudo reaver -i en0 -b 0:18:e7:fb:b1:63 -vv
```

Not certain if I’m using the correct interface, and I can’t find the monitor interface on Mac OS X.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is perhaps a bit late, but I have only just started using Reaver. This error message usually occurs because the Wi-Fi signal is too weak. Reaver tries to connect multiple times while it is running, and if the signal is too weak on one of those connects, you get that error message.

For Reaver to work properly, the signal needs to be really strong and reliable, so you want to be fairly close to the wireless access point.

Comment: Hey David, do you know why I get all timeouts?
It starts OK, and then only timeouts. It happens with all networks.
I am using OS X Capitan and before running reaver I have used: sudo airport en0 sniff 1

[+] Associated with A4:52:6F:0C:5F:84 (ESSID: WiFi-Arnet-1863)
[+] Trying pin 12345670
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred

Thanks in advance